# customer not logged

Tags: magento2, api, login

I'm building rest api to get data based on customer session, but it always returns false when I call isLoggedIn() function

that's my module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">

<module name="Bit68_Cart" setup_version="2.1.15"/>

</config>
```

that's webapi.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">

<route url="/V1/cart/items" method="GET">
    <service class="\Bit68\Cart\Api\Cart\MyCartInterface" method="getItems"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self"/>
    </resources>
</route>

</routes>
```

that's my interface:

```
<?php

namespace Bit68\Cart\Api\Cart;

interface MyCartInterface{

/**
* @api
* @param int $id
* @return bool
*/

public function getItems();

}

?>
```

and that's my class:

```
<?php

namespace Bit68\Cart\Model\Cart;
use Bit68\Cart\Api\Cart\MyCartInterface;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\CartInterface;
use \Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class MyCart implements MyCartInterface{
/**
* @var Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\CartInterface
*/
private $cartObj;

/**
* @var Magento\Customer\Model\Session
*/
private $customerSession;

/**
* @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
* @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cartObj
*/

public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cartObj,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession){
    $this->cartObj = $cartObj;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}

/**
* @api
* @return bool
*/

public function getItems(){

    $customerId = $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();

    return $customerId;
}
}

?>
```

and that's where I call My api:

```
<?php

session_start();

$host = 'http://domain.com/';


if (!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
echo 'Authenticating...<br>';
/*
* authentication details of the customer
*/
$username = 'customer_email';
$password = 'password';
$postData['username'] = $username;
$postData['password'] = $password;

/*
* init curl
*/
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host.'rest/V1/integration/customer/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
/*
* set content type and length
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'Content-Type: application/json',
       'Content-Length: '.strlen(json_encode($postData)),
   )
);
/*
* setpost data
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postData));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
/*
* access token in json format
*/
echo $output;
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $output;
}
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
   /*
   * create headers for authorization
   */
   $headers = array(
       'Authorization: Bearer '.json_decode($_SESSION['access_token']),
   );
   echo '<pre>';
   echo 'api call... with key: '.$_SESSION['access_token'].'<br><br><br>';
   $ch = curl_init();
   /*
   * set api resource url
   */
   $get_params = http_build_query($j);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host.'rest/V1/cart/items');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers
);
   $output = curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);
   echo '<br>';
   echo gettype($output);
   echo '<br>';
   echo $output;
   echo '<br>';
   echo "Today is " . date("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
   /*
    * json response need to rtrim with [], some times it is appended to the respose so the json becomes invalid so need to rtrim the response
   */
   $test = json_decode(rtrim($output, '[]'));
   echo '
   =========================RESPONSE================================<br>
   ';

   print_r($test);
  // echo($test->item_id);
  }
 exit(0);


 ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get customerId during api call you need to follow below code.

```
public function __construct(
 -----
 \Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface $userContext
 -----
){
$this->userContext = $userContext;
}

public function getItems()
{  
 $customerId = $this->userContext->getUserId();
}
```

\Magento\Customer\Model\Session class only used when customer logged in from web interface or storefront. Let me know if you need more help on this.

Comment: Was my answer helpful for you @Yomna ? if yes then please accept it.

Comment: That's working, but what if I need customer session during api, like for example I'm building the Api for mobile app and I need to get cart items for every logged in customer. will \Magento\Customer\Model\Session class help me?

Comment: No you can't use Magento\Customer\Model\Session class during api call. Meanwhile can you please give upvote as well :)

Comment: Let me give you answer, I think you have already ask this question.

Comment: Ok, BTW I have posted answer as well on your question you can check there.